# Making Windows 7 ignore the first click/keystroke when screen is off

Tags: windows, display, power-management

I find this functionality very convenient in OS X, any way I can get Windows 7 to behave similarly?

Comment: I've always just tapped a meta key, like alt or ctrl, to get the screen up without passing any input.

Comment: Good question. Like Xyon, I also just hit Alt, Ctrl, Shift or just move the mouse slightly. Usually, that works, but it relies on the foreground application ignoring such keystrokes. Windows sends these keystrokes, and mouse pointer movements, as Windows events to applications. Most ignore them, but some don't. For example, you may be running a flight simulator that uses the right shift key to roll to the right. So I would be interested in any answer that involves somehow making Windows _not_ send the initial keystroke to applications. -- Edit. Just thought of one: Ctrl-Alt-Del then Cancel.

Comment: Sure, I could just press a meta key, but it's a little pet peeve I have when working on windows that I just want fixed.